# IllegalStateException: No value MyAuthProvider.handleSignup(ctx());

Tags: playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

When calling

MyAuthProvider.handleSignup(ctx());

Play returns **IllegalStateException: No value**

This only happens if I call myAccount.save() before calling.

myAccount is an entity model that I create first before I let the system handle the signup and create a user. I use Ebeans.

**Thread:**

! @6faie6mj9 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/signup] ->

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalStateException: No value]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~ [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value
    at play.libs.F$None.get(F.java:547) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.data.Form.get(Form.java:525) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.password.UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.getSignup(UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.java:153) ~[play-authenticate_2.10-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.password.UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.authenticate(UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.java:84) ~[play-authenticate_2.10-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.feth.play.module.pa.PlayAuthenticate.handleAuthentication(PlayAuthenticate.java:442) ~[play-authenticate_2.10-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.password.UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.handleSignup(UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.java:145) ~[play-authenticate_2.10-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2.5-SNAPSHOT]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using play commands:

```
play clean
play clean-files;
play update
play reload
play compile
play run
```

If you are using activator replace play by activator.